Confusion Regarding the Application of L'Hôpital's Rule in Lecture Notes
In my lecture notes, I came across the following line of working:
$$
\lim_{{h \to 0^+}} \frac{{\arctan\left(\frac{y}{h}\right) - \text{sgn}(y) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}}}{h} = \lim_{{h \to 0^+}} \frac{-\frac{y}{{h^2}}}{1+\left(\frac{y}{h}\right)^2}
$$
where $y$ not equal to $0$. However, I'm having trouble understanding the justification for using L'Hôpital's Rule in this context. Surely this diverges since the numerator converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}.$ Can someone explain why it's appropriate to apply L'Hôpital's Rule in this situation? I'd appreciate any clarification or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Use $ to wrap your LaTeX, not `.

Examine the numerator in cases:  $y>0$ or $y<0$.  In each, the numerator goes to $0$.

@KJM No, it's not.  If $y > 0$ then the $\arctan$ term goes to $\pi/2$, and then $\pi/2-\pi/2=0$.

It helps to understand the parent functions of each piece of the numerator. Looking at the graph and splitting into cases when $y>0$ and $y<0$ should help you see that it's of the form $0/0$

L'Hôpital rule can be applied when you have an indeterminate limit of the form $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{0}{0}$ (or infinity over infinity). In this case, it is obvious that the denominator tends to $0$, let's see the numerator.
$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \arctan\frac{y}{h}$ tends to $\pi/2$ if $y$ is positive and if $y$ is negative it tends to $-\pi/2$. The case $y = 0$ can be ignored since then the denominator is constant. We can separate the problem in two cases:

$y<0$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\arctan{\frac{y}{h}}- \mathrm{sgn}(y)\frac{\pi}{2}}{h} \to \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{-\pi}{2}- (-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}{0} \to \frac{0}{0}
$$
So we can apply l'Hôpital rule.

$y>0$

$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\arctan\frac{y}{h}- \mathrm{sgn}(y)\frac{\pi}{2}}{h} \to \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}- (+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}{0} \to \frac{0}{0}
$$
So we can also apply l'Hôpital in this case
If we take the derivative of the function in respect to $h$, we get to the desired equality.

Edited to fix limits: $h \to 0^+$ and not $h^+ \to 0$.
